# Getting error when try to use React Router v6: Attempted import error: 'Action' is not exported from 'history'

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have created a new react application using

```
npx create-react-app app-name
```

Then I changed my directory to that app folder and then ran the following command.

```
npm install react-router@next react-router-dom@next
```

Then I ran my application and it worked fine. Then I changed the default code and used Routes, Route, etc. Here is APP code

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route} from "react-router-dom"

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

function Home()
{
  return <div>
        <h1>Home</h1>
    </div>
}

export default App;
```

**I get the error:**

```
Attempted import error: 'Action' is not exported from 'history'.
```

Path of the error is:

```
./node_modules/react-router/index.js
```

Any Idea what is wrong with it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with my code. Maybe the issue is with the latest version of React-Router. So, I just changed the version of React-Router.

**FROM**

```
"react-router": "^6.0.0-beta.0"
"react-router-dom": "^6.0.0-beta.0"
```

**TO**

```
"react-router": "6.0.0-alpha.2",
"react-router-dom": "6.0.0-alpha.2"
```

It is working absolutely fine with no problems. The same code that I have mentioned in my question is working fine without any change. :)

Answer (score 6):

You need to install another package called `history`. Do `npm i history`.

More info [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/releases)

Comment: The link provided takes to you to the _releases_ page of react-router, while it does contain an example on howto install react-router along with history package, in the context of this question, sadly... it does not contain more information other than that... :(

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else finding this, @Muhammad solution works as long as you don't rely on `matchPath` export (it doesn't appear to be exported in `alpha.2` release).

But the actual solution is to make sure you've installed `history@^5.0.0`. Once I did that the "missing `Action` export" error went away. So @kcsujeet is right, but just make sure your dependency on `history` is at least 5.0.0.

Comment: This needs to be upvoted. The actual issue is that the version of history is most likely old and needs to be updated.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers have stated, the solution here is to install `history@^5.0.0`. However, if you're using TypeScript you might still run into  the `'Action' is not exported from 'history'` error. You need to remove `@types/react-router`/`@types/react-router-dom` from your `devDependencies`.

In react-router 5.x, types were not bundled so you needed to install `@types/react-router-dom`. In the 6.0 prerelease, types are already bundled so you don't need to explicitly install them. And if you keep the 5.x types around, they're out of date and also pull in a dependency on `@types/history` 4.x, which is also out of date.

So if you're upgrading to react-router 6.0 in a TypeScript project, remove the unnecessary types.

Answer (score 0):

`npm i history`

By installing this your problem will resolve this happens in older version of React DOM 5

Answer (score -1):

Instead of importing Routes component, import Switch component...
There is not Routes component in the package.

Comment: No, the thing is that since v6, Switch is replaced by Routes.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Found the solution.. :)