# Error: 'Action' is not exported from 'history'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes

I haven't imported action anywhere and it says  'Action' is not exported from 'history'. I don't even know what action is.
info: I reinstalled the previous version of history as I was having problems with routing when my history was updated
Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import './App.css';
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar/Navbar";
import Home from './components/Pages/Home';
import Intro from './components/Pages/Intro';
import LogIn from './components/Pages/LogIn';
import SignUp from './components/Pages/SignUp';
import Recomendations from './components/Pages/Recomendations';
import Reviewed from './components/Pages/Reviewed';
import AboutUs from './components/Pages/AboutUs';
import Bookmarks from './components/Pages/Bookmarks';
import Error from './components/Pages/Error';
import { Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';


function App() {
  
    return (
      <div>
        
        
      <Navbar />
      <Router>
        <Route exact path='/'  component={Intro} />
        <Route path='/intro'  component={Intro} />
        <Route path='/error'  component={Error} />
      </Router>
      </div>
    );
   
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the version of `history` package, and make sure it is somewhat recent. Someone else had a similar problem: [Getting error when try to use React Router v6: Attempted import error: 'Action' is not exported from 'history'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63071718/getting-error-when-try-to-use-react-router-v6-attempted-import-error-action)